# Pretty Print JSON in Node's REPL/Interactive Mode

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop

By entering the comande `node` from the command line, [node will start a REPL](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/repl.html).  From within this REPL, is there a way to pretty print JSON?

E.g.:
From Bash:

```
Now using node v12.14.1 (npm v6.13.6)
:~/Code/tmp$ node
```

Starts an REPL:

```
Welcome to Node.js v12.14.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
> msg =  { "hello":"world", "quantity": 1 }
```

Executing `JSON.stringify(msg)` produces:

```
'{"hello":"world","quantity":1}'
```

Executing `JSON.stringify(msg, null, 2)` produces:

```
'{\n  "hello": "world",\n  "quantity": 1\n}'
```

What I want is:

```
{
  "hello": "world",
  "quantity": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` returns a string that is not interpreted into the node console.

If you want the string to be interpreted use `console.log(JSON.stringify(msg, null, 2))` .

**Note**: What `console.log` is displaying is a string, there is no more interpretation of the data *(color yellow on the number, green for the string ...)*

[image]